# What is sgn(321)?

Tags: permutations

[image]I've tried to compute the length of (321) and I got 2. Then the sgn should be (-1)^2=1. But I suppose sgn(321)=-1 by the definition in the graph?

Comment: The length of $(321)$ is $3$. The number of transpositions when $(321)$ is written as the product of transpositions is even.

Comment: The signature of a cycle of length $k$ is $(-1)^{k-1}$.